# Computing vector load and stores

Tags: data-structures, memory-access

If $a,b,c,y$ are all scalar doubles, then $y = a\cdot b$ would result in 16 bytes from loading $a,b$ and 8 bytes for storing $y$, a total of 24 bytes transferred. Likewise, $y = a\cdot b + c$ results in 24 bytes from loading $a,b,c$ and 8 for storing $y$ hence 32 total bytes transferred. Now let $\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{Y},\boldsymbol{Z}$ be vectors of size N and $w$ be a scalar. How many total bytes transferred (loads/stores) would the following operations take

1) $\boldsymbol{Z} = w\boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{Y}$

2) $w = \boldsymbol{X}\cdot\boldsymbol{Y}$

My guess would be 4*N*8 and (2*N+1)*8 respectively for these reasons:

1) I load two vectors of size N, load a scalar N times, and store a vector of size N.

2) I load two vectors of size N, and do a reduction that stores a single scalar.

If what I have is incorrect, what should the answers be?

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Answer (score 1):

In formulating an answer it would be really helpful to understand *why* you are trying to calculate this. If it's a theoretical exercise then your reasoning may hold however if it's for any real application, it fails to take into account compiler optimisation and the fact that values may be in L1 cache or registers rather than being loaded from L2 or other storage.

It also overlooks the fact that many modern, optimised matrix libraries would vectorise the vector operations using GPU or even the CPU's multiple cores which would make this type of calculation far from simple.

Any answer would depend on what you are assuming about your CPU architecture and it's capabilities so there's no *right* answer per-se. Also, even assuming a naive CPU architecture with a single accumulator, you didn't specify the data type of the vectors

Comment: I am using the Roofline Model to assess the performance of my scientific code written in PETSc. This model determines the upper bound performance (FLOPS/s) based on the stream BW times the arithmetic intensity (AI). AI is the ratio of total FLOPs (manually counted) over total DRAM bytes. The latter is what I am attempting to calculate. A major assumption that this model makes is that there is no register reuse (which indeed could lead to an answer off by several orders of magnitude) but this does not matter for pure streaming computations (vectors of type double) as what I have above.

Comment: Given the assumptions you make above (maybe add these to your question for clarity?) then (1) would be 4xNx8 as you say.  (2) is more debatable. If your reduction is e.g. dot product then you would need to store the result of each per element multiplication, then reload them to sum them. This would be ( (4xN)+1) * 8 bytes.  (though you could save one read here). Calculating the  L1 Norm of the difference vector would require only ((2xN)+1) * 8 bytes.